# Verificar se um usuario cadastrado no banco possue cpf já cadastrado

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, mvc, codeigniter-3

Olá, pessoal eu tô precisando verificar no banco se um usuário logado já possue cpf cadastrado e retornar se é falso ou  não.

Uso o codeigniter na aplicação. Vou mandar os códigos. 
CONTROLLER:

```
public function check_cpf_doctor() { 
$check_result = $this->Doctor_model->checkCPFDoctor($_POST['doctor_id']);
  print json_encode($check_result);
}
```

// DOCTOR_MODEL

```
public function checkCPFDoctor($id)
{
    $key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');

    $query = 

    if($query['crm'])

    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}
```

essa query do model tá errada e incompleta pq não consegui finalizar, quero que retorne os dados do usuário que está logado.

Comment: Você tem um botão para checar ou está chegando em Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `form_validation` no seu `Controller` é possível validar se um valor é unico, informando a tabela e valor pesquisado:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpf', 'Cpf', 'required|is_unique[doctors.cpf]');
```

Para pegar os erros basta utilizar a chamada `validation_errors();`

OBS: troque doctors pelo nome da sua tabela, caso este não seja o nome dela.

> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
// Controller
public function check_cpf_doctor() { 
    $check_result = $this->Doctor_model->checkCPFDoctor($this->input->post('doctor_id'));
    if($check_result==1){
        echo "Este CPF já está cadastrado";
    } else {
        echo "CPF não cadastrado";
    }
}

// Model
public function checkCPFDoctor(){
    $this->db->where('cpf', $this->input->post('doctor_id'));
    $check = $this->db->get('table')->num_rows();
    return $check;
}
```

Neste caso, retornamos com num_rows(), em caso de retorno 1, ele já está cadastrado, se não, ele não está cadastrado.